# Several data source in Play 2 framework with slick

Tags: database, scala, playframework-2.0, slick-3.0, play-slick

How can I configure and use several data source in `Play 2.5.x Framework` with `Slick`? 
For example, one data source should be `MySQL` and another `PostgreSQL`.

```
  slick.dbs.default.driver = "utils.db.TetraoPostgresProfile$"
  slick.dbs.default.db.driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
  slick.dbs.default.db.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/templatesite_db"
  slick.dbs.default.db.user = "user"
  slick.dbs.default.db.password = "pass"

  slick.dbs.secondary.driver = "slick.jdbc.MySQLProfile$"
  slick.dbs.secondary.db.driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  slick.dbs.secondary.db.url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbName"
  slick.dbs.secondary.db.user = "root"
  slick.dbs.secondary.db.password = "pass"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is directly addressed in the ScalaDatabase docummentation page:

```
// inject "orders" database instead of "default"
class ScalaInjectNamed @Inject()(
  @NamedDatabase("orders") db: Database) extends Controller {
  // do whatever you need with the db
}
```

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlaySlick#usage

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDatabase#obtaining-a-jdbc-connection